# Static variable in Php Trait is not working

Tags: php, traits

// Solved
// I didn't echo output

I want to test static variable in traits.
what is the issue of static $city variable.
Here why $o::$city is not working

===============

```
trait Chargeable
{
    public static $city = 'Dhaka';
    public function charge()
    {
        echo "I am a Chargeable trait mehtod...... <br />";
    }
    abstract public function sayHello();

    public static function myHello()
    {
        echo "Say My Hello ... ";
    }

}

class Toy
{

}

class ElectricCarToy extends Toy
{
    use Chargeable;

    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo "Helloooo ....... <br />";
    }
}

$o = new ElectricCarToy();
$o->charge();
$o->sayHello();

echo $o::$city;
$o::myHello();
```

======================
Output:

```
I am a Chargeable trait mehtod......
Helloooo .......
Say My Hello ...
```

Comment: Just copied your code and run it. Works exactly as expected and print out also the city.

Answer (score 0):

please echo or print it like below

```
echo $o::$city.'<br />';
print($o::$city.'<br />');
```